# Add spacing between input boxes via CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm currently having some trouble trying to add spacing between some input boxes. I have tried  adding `padding` to it but all it does is move the boxes, not so much put spaces in between them.

My code is as follows:

```css
.test { 
  padding:20px 20px 20px 20px;
}
.ModifiedValues { 
  position: absolute;
  left: 250px;
  top: 20px;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ModifiedValues">
  <center><b>New Value</b></center>
  <span class="test"><input type="text" name="firstname" value="" style="text-align:left;"><br></span>
  <span class="test"><input type="text" name="firstname" value="" style="text-align:left;"><br></span>
  <span class="test"><input type="text" name="firstname" value="" style="text-align:left;"><br></span>
  <span class="test"><input type="text" name="firstname" value="" style="text-align:left;"><br></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Add display:block to span .test. By default, it is inline element...

Comment: Many thanks, this has worked

Comment: Next time you ask a question, please be more specific about the desired result. It was totally unclear that you wanted ***vertical*** space. And btw. `center` has been deprecated for roughly 33 years now.

Comment: @connexo - it was clear enough if you had a look at the code and current result. there was no reason for horizontal space.

Comment: @RuhulAmin - have a look at his own answer ealier than yours and the comment of @ nevermind

Comment: Or simply replace `span` by `div` (which by default has `display: block;`). You should not use `span` when you want a block level element that yields no semantic meaning.

Comment: @alexjohnson,You have invalid `input` markup. Also it's not a good practice to use inline css. I fixed your HTML code and CSS both. Have a  look my answer.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch, Sorry, I did not copy your answer, it might be same but I wanted to give him complete solution. You can have a look my answer

Comment: @RuhulAmin `<input type="text">` is not *invalid HTML* as opposed to `<input type="text" />` (even though I'd agree to prefer the latter). It's only *invalid XML*.

Comment: @connexo Not sure, where did you see, this is the markup`<input type="text" name="firstname" value=""/>`

Answer (score 0):

answer proposed by 'nevermind' has worked :)

```
display:block;
```

Comment: That's correct but still it did not fix your markup(HTML) problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `display: block`. Have a look:

```css
.test { 
  padding:5px 20px;
  display: block;
}
.ModifiedValues { 
  position: absolute;
  left: 250px;
  top: 20px;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 12px;
} 

.ModifiedValues { 
        position: absolute;
        left: 250px;
        top: 20px;
        color: #666;
        font-size: 12px;
     }
```

```html
<div class="ModifiedValues">
    <center><b>New Value</b></center>
    <span class="test"><input type="text" name="firstname" value=""/></span>
    <span class="test"><input type="text" name="firstname" value=""/></span>
    <span class="test"><input type="text" name="firstname" value=""/></span>
    <span class="test"><input type="text" name="firstname" value=""/></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you still using `<br>` in this solution instead of simply adding a `margin-bottom` to the `span` elements?

Comment: Not even needed. Just removed unwanted `<br>` tag, also fixed the `input` tag

Answer (score -1):

You can test this code. It works

```
.ModifiedValues { 
  position: absolute;
  left: 250px;
  top: 20px;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.test { 
margin: 10px !important;
text-align: left;

}

<div class="ModifiedValues">
  <center><b>New Value</b></center>
  <div class="test">
        <span><input type="text" name="firstname" value="" ></span>
  </div>
   <div class="test">
        <span><input type="text" name="firstname" value="" ></span>
  </div>
   <div class="test">
        <span><input type="text" name="firstname" value="" ></span>
  </div>
   <div class="test">
        <span><input type="text" name="firstname" value="" ></span>
  </div>
   <div class="test">
        <span><input type="text" name="firstname" value="" ></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any given value for `id` ***must be unique per document***. Also, why did you keep the `span` elements here?